# Difference between one wifi router and another?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

I really don't know much about this, so please bear with me.

I recently purchased a `Netgear R6300` at walmart because I wanted my wireless signal to reach our attic, which has no electrical outlets. Since it was on sale, I bought it. The only purpose was to extend the wireless signal.

But it seems that the range is more or less the same as my older `trendnet tew-810dr`, and the signal seems to be pretty bad in the attic. So I'm thinking that the issue may be that these routers are not built for this.

So my question is: what's the difference between the router that I just bought and the wireless routers with the antennas (netgear rangemax, tp-link AC122 or N300 or N450, etc)?

Thanks.

Comment: "what's the difference between the router that I just bought and the wireless routers with the antennas" - The bandwidth thats possible which is determined by broadband chipset.  The `netgear rangemax` is a 802.11n router, the R6300 and AC122 are both 802.11ac.  I am not going to compare more then that.

Comment: I don't know what to RESEARCH, that's why I'm asking. But thanks for your useful comment.

Comment: @Ramhound, would this chipset improve the wireless range? I looked at this [link](http://www.securedgenetworks.com/blog/802-11ac-vs-802-11n-Infographic-Which-wireless-solutions-are-better) and it seems that the difference is seen in the connection speed. But I only care about range.

Comment: @rbhatup - No;The differences between the different 802.11ac waves are well documented, their range, remain mainly unchanged though.

Comment: The physical distance between the router and my ipad is about 20 feet, and then there's the solid concrete division (easily a foot thick) which would be the ceiling. Is it possible that the ceiling and 20-ft of distance is enough to limit the signal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no "commercial" difference. Both pretty much have the same range in the same band (it all depends on technical specificities we wouldn't know about as customers). If you want to expand your existing WiFi network, you'd better use a WiFi repeater.

Your Netgear R6300 [has the capability to do so](https://www.manualslib.com/manual/409587/Netgear-R6300.html?page=86) (follow the link), so no need to buy another one. Just configure it using the web interface and put it between your attic and your initial AP. You should have a better connection in it this way.

Comment: Thanks. The problem is that there aren't any electrical outlets in the attic.

Comment: The physical distance between the router and my ipad is about 20 feet, and then there's the solid concrete division (easily a foot thick) which would be the ceiling. Is it possible that the ceiling and 20-ft of distance is enough to limit the signal?

Comment: It's possible, but you don't need to put the repeater in the attic, you just have to put it closer to it than the initial AP is.